# Automatic ZFS Snapshots on Solaris 10

Tags: solaris, zfs, snapshot

I'm trying to enable automatic ZFS snapshotting on a Solaris 10 server.
From extensive googling, I've managed to understand that there are/were some automated services to do this, like:

- http://mij.oltrelinux.com/devel/zfsbackup/

And even locate a manual of sorts for a built in service:

- http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19120-01/open.solaris/817-2271/6mhupg6oc/index.html

Alas, on the Solaris I'm working on, I can't seem to find the "Time Slider" service, nor the auto-snapshot service other articles refer to, that is supposed to be built in, and simply enabled.

Does anyone know how I can install/enable this service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This service isn't available for Solaris 10, you need an OpenSolaris based distribution or Solaris 11 Express to get it.
Of course, nothing prevents you to re-implement it but you will miss the Gnome file manager integration.

Comment: I got the same answer from Oracle support... Apparently it's not in Solaris 10. If someone could suggest an alternative tool, it would be great... Thanks :)

Comment: Have a look at this blog entry. Some people managed to use the previous zfs automatic snapshot implementation on Solaris 10. http://blogs.sun.com/timf/entry/zfs_automatic_snapshots_0_12

Answer (score 0):

Could it be part of the GNOME file manager package ?

In Solaris 11 express its listed as:

*Time Slider ZFS Snapshots management for GNOME 
pkg:/desktop/time- slider@...*